# ElasticSearch: reindex and aliases (keep routing policy)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using alias per user. For each alias I'm linking a `routing` and a `filter`:

```
PUT _/<index>/_alias/u1@u1.com'
{
  "routing": "u1@u1.com",
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "user": "u1@u1.com"
    }
  }
}
```

So, I'm setting that indexation and searching is using `routing` information.

I want to reindex all documents on another index using `_reindex` api. After having created the new index, I've created all aliases. So, I figure out that documents have to be reindexed using aliases in order to keep routing policy.

Is there any way to set it up on `_reindex`?

Example:

```
POST _/_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new"
  }
}
'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old",
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "user": "u1@u1.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new",
    "routing": "=u1@u1.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a loook on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html):

> By default if `_reindex` sees a document with routing then the routing is preserved unless it’s changed by the script.

So, as far I've been able to figure out, by default, for each document that already has a `routing` information it's preserved.